# git: inspect the contents of files in other branches without modifying any repositories

Tags: git

I need to work on another branch, and don't know which branch. Several are listed and I can determine which branch I need based on the contents of certain key files. Is there a way to just take a peek at some of the files in the branches? Also, is this where I use `stash`?

Comment: Thank you. Just a matter of searching for the right words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git show branch:file
```

Will work :)

You can also run

```
git grep pattern branch
```

So you can grep files from other branches

You can use `git checkout` to bring the file from the other branch.